# Next 13 filter blog posts client / server components

Tags: next.js

I've just started a new project using Next 13 but struggling to wrap my head around the best way to handle filtering of data. I have a directory page which loads blogs posts server side and a filter component which is set to be a client component as it handles the clicking of filters.

I have the blog directory page at `/app/blog/page.tsx` which contains this code

```
import React from "react";

import BlogGrid from "@/app/components/BlogGrid/BlogGrid";
import TagFilters from "@/app/components/TagFilters/TagFilters";
import { getBlogs, getTags } from "@/sanity/sanity-utils";

export default async function BlogDirectory() {
  const blogs = await getBlogs();
  const tags = await getTags();

  return (
    <section className="px-2 md:px-5">
      <TagFilters tags={tags} handleFilter={handleFilter} />
      <BlogGrid blogs={blogs} />
    </section>
  );
}

export const revalidate = 3600;
```

In my tagFilters.tsx I have

```
"use client";

import React from "react";

import type { SanityTags } from "@/types/document-types";

type TagProps = {
  tags: SanityTags;
  handleFilter: (tagName: string) => void;
};

export default function TagFilters({ tags, handleFilter }: TagProps) {
  return (
    <div className="flex my-4 space-x-2">
      {tags &&
        tags.map((tag, index) => {
          return (
            <button
              key={`tag-${index + 1}`}
              className="px-2 py-1 text-white rounded-md bg-primary"
              onClick={() => handleFilter(tag.name)}
            >
              {tag.name}
            </button>
          );
        })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

It's at this point now I don't know the best way to go, I could add this function to my page.tsx and create a state array to manage the blogs but then I'd need to make the page.tsx a client side component which doesn't seem right?

```
async function handleFilter(filter: string) {
  "use server";

  const blogs = await getBlogs(filter);

  setBlogs(blogs);
}
```

Any pointers on a way to handle this would be appreciated